# How to get out-of-sample forecasts from predict function

Tags: r, prediction

I'm using the `vars` package and want to predict some values from the calculated models:

```
# Get the model
x1 <- rnorm(15)
y1 <- x1 + rnorm(15)
trainFrame=data.frame(x1,y1);
model=VAR(trainFrame, p=3);
pr1=predict(model, trainFrame);
# Forecast values with new data
x2 <- rnorm(15)
y2 <- x2 + rnorm(15)
newFrame=data.frame(x2,y2);
pr2=predict(model, newFrame);
```

Comparing the two prediction vectors `pr1` and `pr2` shows that they are the same.
How can I get the actual forecast values and not again the forecasts from the training data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you call the predict method for objects with class attribute `varest`.

> predict(object, ..., n.ahead = 10, ci = 0.95, dumvar = NULL)

n.ahead forecasts are computed recursively for the estimated VAR.

No need to give the training Frame to predict.

```
  pr2=pr1=predict(model)
```

Comment: This doe not answer the question: why are pr1 and pr2 the same, although they have definitely a different data base generated by the rnorm calls?

Comment: @Juergen they are the same becausesimply we don't use the generated data to predict. Only the model.predict(model)

Comment: How can I use the generated data newFrame? Forecasting in-sample does not make much sense.

Comment: Generated newframe?? generated how?I think you are a little bit confusing about Var model. What do you try to do have no sense. Here the prediction is a forecast of futures values not a fitting. did you read this http://www.jstatsoft.org/v27/i04/paper?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (I think), so I wrote this function to calculate the n-step ahead forecast. It doesn't give the error band or the CI though.

```
VAR.pred <- function(x, varest, n.ahead = 10)
{
 k <- ncol(varest$y)
 p <- varest$p
 Atemp <- matrix(NA, k, k*p + 1)

 for(i in 1:k) Atemp[i, ] <- (coef(varest)[[i]])[, 1]

 Const <- as.matrix(Atemp[, ncol(Atemp)])
 A <- Atemp[, -ncol(Atemp)]

 fcast <- matrix(NA, n.ahead, k)
 spoint <- as.matrix(x[nrow(x):(nrow(x)- p + 1), ])

 for(l in 1:n.ahead)
 {
  ftemp <- A[, 1:k]%*%t(spoint)[, 1]
  for(j in 2:p)   ftemp <- ftemp + A[, (1 + k*(j-1)):(k*j)]%*%t(spoint)[, j]
  ftemp <- ftemp + Const

  fcast[l, ] <- t(ftemp) 

  spoint <- rbind(t(ftemp), spoint)[1:p, ]
 }

 fframe <- data.frame(fcast)
 names(fframe) <- dimnames(x)[[2]]

 return(fframe)
}
```

Gives pr1

```
VAR.pred(x = model$y, varest = model)
```

Gives pr2

```
VAR.pred(x = newFrame, varest = model)
```

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that they are not the same is that the rnorm function is generating two different sets of random data i.e the data being used in parts 1 and 2 is simply not the same.

To check see:

```
y1 <- rnorm(15)
y1
 [1] -0.05346192  0.34168852 -0.18398645  0.84534239 -0.97027620  0.39889488
 [7] -0.44039372  0.03008880  0.47940826 -0.73258837  1.06715936 -0.93316881
[13] -1.38306019 -0.42179145 -0.84193860

y2 <- rnorm(15) 
y2
 [1] -1.5849866  1.0203186  0.6242200 -0.5064240 -0.9497568 -0.2460866
 [7] -0.8262738  0.3100040  0.1352368  0.4030656 -0.7095272 -0.2856932
[13] -0.9061068  1.5968001  1.0259594
```

You will find that y1 and y2 are not the same.

To make sure the rnorm function generates the same set of data, you can use the function `"set.seed()"`, which ensure that your work is reproducible.